# Getting the following error while using langchain in Jupyter: TypeError: dataclass_transform() got an unexpected keyword argument 'field_specifiers'

Tags: jupyter-notebook, openai-api, langchain

I've been trying to use langchain in my Jupyter notebook but it keeps throwing the following error:

```
TypeError: dataclass_transform() got an unexpected keyword argument 'field_specifiers'
```

My installation seems to have been successful after I used %pip install langchain but when I try to import any module or package like from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI, it throws the error.

Full error details:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
      2 from langchain.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate
      3 from langchain.chains import LLMChain

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain/__init__.py:5, in <module>
      1 """Main entrypoint into package."""
      3 from typing import Optional
----> 5 from langchain.agents import MRKLChain, ReActChain, SelfAskWithSearchChain
      6 from langchain.cache import BaseCache
      7 from langchain.callbacks import (
      8     set_default_callback_manager,
      9     set_handler,
     10     set_tracing_callback_manager,
     11 )

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain/agents/__init__.py:2, in <module>
      1 """Interface for agents."""
----> 2 from langchain.agents.agent import Agent, AgentExecutor
      3 from langchain.agents.agent_toolkits import (
      4     create_csv_agent,
      5     create_json_agent,
   (...)
     10     create_vectorstore_router_agent,
     11 )
     12 from langchain.agents.conversational.base import ConversationalAgent

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain/agents/agent.py:11, in <module>
      8 from typing import Any, Dict, List, Optional, Sequence, Tuple, Union
     10 import yaml
---> 11 from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator
     13 from langchain.agents.tools import InvalidTool
     14 from langchain.callbacks.base import BaseCallbackManager

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydantic/__init__.py:2, in init pydantic.__init__()

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydantic/dataclasses.py:46, in init pydantic.dataclasses()

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydantic/main.py:121, in init pydantic.main()

TypeError: dataclass_transform() got an unexpected keyword argument 'field_specifiers'
```

I tried using conda as well but the error persisted and also tried a specific langchain version like pip install langchain==0.0.125 but to no avail

Comment: Have you set your environment using pip?